# WSO2 apimcli environment adding for API manager in fully distributed environment and using wso2 Identity server as key manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm trying to create an environment for API manager in fully distributed Environment and using WSO2 identity server as key manager. Any inputs for creation of environments in fully distributed environment?

Note: using WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 and APIMCLI tool 2.0.3 and supported .war file.

Comment: The question is not clear. What did you try? Did you get any errors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25046048 please check this one

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [1] to configure WSO2 IS as Key manager. Then follow [2] to configure API Manager as a distributed setup. In there, use WSO2 IS as the key manager.

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Deploying+WSO2+API-M+in+a+Distributed+Setup

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the documents provided by 'Pubci' to deploy a single environment in a distributed manner. I assume your requirement is to then export and import the APIs created in this environment to another environment, where the CLI tool can be set up for the purpose including both the environments in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the valuable suggestions.

We have distributed environment as below and trying to export published API from the same.

1. Identity Server as WSO2 KeyManager -> https://key-m:9443/carbon
2. WSO2 Traffic and Publisher --> https://traffic:9443/carbon  , https://publisher:9444/carbon
3. WSO2 Internal Gateway --> https://internal-gw:9443/carbon
4. WSO2 External Gateway --> https://external-gw:9443/carbon
5. WSO2 Store --> https://store:9443/carbon

We have deployed "api-import-export-2.6.0-v14.war" in  https://external-gw:9443/carbon and cli tool in the same server.

We have added environment as below,

apimcli add-env -n dev \
                      --registration https://store:9443/client-registration/v0.14/register \
                      --apim https://external-gw:9443 \
                      --token https://key-m:9443/token \
                      --import-export https://external-gw:9443/api-import-export-2.6.0-v10 \
                      --admin https://external-gw:9443/api/am/admin/v0.14 \
                      --api_list https://publisher:9444/api/am/publisher/v0.14/apis \
                      --app_list https://store:9443/api/am/store/v0.14/applications

When we tried to login through cli tool to dev environment, we are getting "403:forbidden".

Suspecting while creating environment, we might have mis-configured urls for registration/apim/token/import-import/admin/api_list/app_list.

Any help will be highly appreciated.